# after adding redirect javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

after adding new rule

```
# Redirect /post_pu.php?id_pu=1 to /pu/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+post_pu\.php\?id_pu=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pu/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally redirect /pu/1 to /post_pu.php?id_pu=1 
RewriteRule ^pu/([0-9]+)/?$ post_pu.php?id_pu=$1 [NC,L]
```

javascript doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pu/comment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addclasskillclass.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/attachevent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addcss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabtastic.js"></script>
```

How it can be fixed?

Comment: need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to add. This allows apache to serve existed files as is.

Comment: in this case RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+post_pu\.php\?id_pu=([0-9]+) [NC] I got an error: Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: it's separate condition. you can have multiple conditions for each rule

Comment: You have to add rule for your script file to otherwise it will not added or load. if you are using chrome browser then you check in network tab of developer tool that your script file loaded or not. if it not loaded you will found 404 error for it.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

I fit it
I just added slash / before file.php